# Vitest HTML Reporter only shows white page

Tags: reactjs, vite, vitest, test-reporting

I set up Vitest in a React/Vite project, everything runs fine and the tests work. But as we added the report to our server as html report the page stays blank. There is not even a console error. Also when running the html report locally with:

```
npx vite preview --outDir reports/html
```

nothing happens. Maybe someone already had the same problem and knows how to solve it? This is our test property in the vite.config:

```
test: {
  globals: true,
  environment: 'jsdom',
  setupFiles: ['src/setupTest.ts'],
  reporters: ['junit', 'html'],
  outputFile: { junit: './reports/junit/junit-report.xml', html: './reports/html/index.html' },
  coverage: {
    reportsDirectory: './reports/coverage',
    reporter: ['cobertura'],
  },
},
```

Thanks in advance!